# angularjs - isolated scope in directive and actions

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.4 and I am creating a directive/component that is like the new component helper:

```
var invoiceSearchComonent = ['invoiceDataService', function (invoiceDataService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: path.fromRoot("/application/invoices/views/invoicesearch.html"),
    controller: InvoiceSearchController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
}];

module.directive('invoicesearch', invoiceSearchComonent);
```

I have a typeahead in the template and other controls and from this component, I want to let the outside world know that the search criteria has changed.

Is the best way to use `$emit` to publish an event when the user input has changed?  I really do not like this approach of using string name values to publish events.

In react and ember, it is possible to pass action functions around but I am new to react and don't know the best way of achieving this apart from `$emit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, but you can bind variables to the new scope, so something like

```
var invoiceSearchComonent = ['invoiceDataService', function (invoiceDataService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {userInput: '='},
    templateUrl: path.fromRoot("/application/invoices/views/invoicesearch.html"),
    controller: InvoiceSearchController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
}];
```

and then when using the directive

```
<invoice-search user-input=vm.userInput></invoice-search>
```

then whenever the userInput variable changes inside your directive template this change will make it to the outside scope.

Additionally, you can pass in functions to directives using a similar sort of binding (& replaces =)